# Dependency Injection of factory of objects

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

If we have several classes looks like:

```
@Device()
@Model("some model")
@Variant("A")
public class SomeModelVariantA extends BaseDevice {

    public SomeModelVariantA (InputStream in, OutputStream out, int encoding) throws IOException {
        super(in, out, encoding);
    }

    @Override
    @CommandSpec("41")
    @WithoutArguments
    @WithoutResponse
    public Response init(Command args) throws NotSupportedException, IOException {
        return null;
    }
```

I generate class implementation using JavaPoet and annotation processing.
I have project for all annotations I use, project compiler which have Annotation processor to handle annotated classes and Application project with annotated, generated classes and other logic. All generated classes extends base `BaseDevice` class and looks like:

```
/**
 * Generated on Fri Aug 28 11:03:21 EEST 2015
 */
public final class SomeModelVariantA extends BaseDevice {
  public SomeModelVariantA (InputStream arg0, OutputStream arg1, int arg2) throws IOException {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
  }

  @Override
  public Response init(Command arg0) throws NotSupportedException, IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    Response response = new Response();

    customCommand(41, builder.toString());
    return response;
  }
```

I have generated several concrete devices and next step is to create an api working with these devices.

```
public class Api {

    BaseDevice device;

    Api(String device, InputStream is, OutputStream os, int encoding) {
        if ("SomeModelVariandA1".contentEquals(device)) {
            device = new SomeModelVariantA(is, os, encoding);
        }
        ... else if for other devices
    }

    public void callInit() {
        device.init(null);
    }
}
```

So how can I generate factory for all devices and inject device by some String name into the Api class. How can I handle providing a device created with input and output stream from the api constructor. Is dagger 2 and google auto factory suitable for this purpose and can someone provide an example usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set to `concreteClass` full class name (package+class name) and then use `Class.forName(concreteClass)`

For example, if you have `ClassA` defined in `com.blablabla.classes` package, you need to set to `concreteClass` value `"com.blablabla.classes.ClassA"`. 
Then, if you want to create class-objects only which extends `BaseClass`, you need to define new class like this:

`Class<T extends BaseClass> injectedClass = Class.forName(concreteClass);`
Or, if you want to create all class-objects, you need to define:

`Class injectedClass = Class.forName(concreteClass);`

Comment: I tried to generate factory but cannot resolve these concrete classes with `Class.forName(concreteClass)`.
Generation logic is in compiler project and the generated classes are in other.

Comment: Can you provide code example? I can't understand about `compiler project`. If you mean, they are in different jars, so, you need to include this jar in your classpath.

Comment: I have 3 projects - annotations, compiler and application project. I have annotated classes in application project and using compiler project I generate using annotation processor these concrete classes in application project.